# How do you diagnose the exception code 0xc0000409 on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++

I have a C++ windows application that was done by another programmer, that I had to remove one line of code. After rebuilding the application with visual studio 2013 it crashes with this in the event log:

```
Faulting application name: WaveStream.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x536122da
Faulting module name: WaveStream.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x536122da
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0000bd7f
Faulting process id: 0x8b8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf6490aee4f557
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PS Audio\WaveStream.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PS Audio\WaveStream.exe
Report Id: efe00d42-d083-11e3-a513-bc305baf9e1e
```

The application uses QT 4.7.4, and compiles with no errors. I am an embedded systems programmer and have very little windows programing experience. What can I do to figure out why it is crashing?

Comment: You could build the debug build and attach to it using visual studio, it should break once this fault occurs

Comment: Like I said, I am not very familiar with programing in the visual studio environment. I am not sure how to do that, can you point me to a HowTo link?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx, are you sure that the single line of code you removed is that cause? What happens if you put it back and can you post this code so long as it's not too long.

Comment: Put the line of code back in and find out why it's so important.

Comment: I am positive the line of code I removed is not the issue. I put it back and still have the issue.I am sure it is in my build environment or system setup.

Answer (score 30):

The clue to the problem is in the exception code: 0xc0000409

**0xc0000409** means **STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN**.

In other words, something in your program is writing past the current stack frame, corrupting data on the stack. The program has detected this and rather than let it continue, has thrown an exception.

How do you debug this? There are a few options:

**1)** Rerun this in the debugger and watch it crash, workout what failed.

**2)** If you've got a crash dump of this, load that in the debugger, hit F5 and workout what failed.

**3)** If you don't have a crash dump you can still attempt to find out the cause of the crash if you know the absolute address of the crash (and know the module always loads at a fixed address), or if you know the offset of the crash location from the start of the faulting module.

The crash information above tells you the offset into the faulting module of the crash. That's reported in the Fault Offset field. In your example, that is an offset of 0x0000bd7f.

If you've got the original dll/exe and it's matching PDB, just load it into [DbgHelpBrowser](https://www.softwareverify.com/cpp-dbghelp-browser.php), go to the **Query** menu, choose **"Find Symbol with DLL Relative Address..."** then enter the offset in the field and click **"Find Symbol..."**. The display will move to show you the nearest matching symbol, highlighting the symbol and display any info about parameters, line numbers and source code.

It's a free tool. You can get it here:
https://www.softwareverify.com/cpp-dbghelp-browser.php

*Disclaimer. I wrote this tool to do just this job for our in house use. We recently made it available for everyone else. I found this question while trying to understand what the exception code 0xc0000409 meant.*

Comment: Unfortunately (in my experience, anyway) the offset given is the address of the code that raises the error -- the implemnetation that tries to invoke Watson to do the reporting. It's not the actual location of the fault. Since the issue here is memory ocrruption, the code that did the corruption is gone and it's the code that notice the canary was killed that's raising the problem. This might get you to the right function, but it's not the offset reported in the log.

Comment: @MikeB: C0000409 is a [fail-fast exception](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside/C0000409). In general, SEH exceptions due to memory corruption can be reported much later, but this is an exception to the rule (pun intended)

Comment: Note that STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN usually doesn’t mean that there was a stack buffer overrun, it just means that the application decided to terminate itself with great haste. More details [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190108-00/?p=100655).

Answer (score 4):

Try to create a crash dump for the application. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764885/exe-crashing-i-have-fault-offset-how-to-match-to-c-source-code-in-vs2012) and the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181.aspx) on how to do that. Once you have the crash dump file, open it in the Visual Studio debugger and you will be able to see the exception and call stack for the exception, which should help.

Answer (score -7):

!analyize -v in windbg

It will do a lot of work for you.