# How can I avoid SQL issue?

Tags: python, sql, database, db2

When I run my query I got this issue  ---  pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0010 - String constant beginning "        " not delimited. (-10) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Can someone help me please!

```
cursor = db2_conn.cursor()
cursor.execute
("select * from qs36f.DSTHSTP join qs36f.calendar on date_ccyymmd = dhindt join qs36f.itemp i on DHITM#=i.ZIITM# join qs36f.subcl2p on i.zisbcl = s2sbcl and i.ziclss = s2clss join qs36f.subclsp on sbclss=s2clss and SBSBCL=s2sbcl where date_iso between(current date - 10 day) and current date and DHCUS# in (" + open_stores + ") and dhqtss >= 1 and SBDEPT='MT' AND dhclss = " + class_nbr + " and ((dhqtss*dhrt5s)*DHPACK) > " + start_range + "")
```

I tried run this query and get some data from db for testing. With this query I should get store number, item number and price greater than 250.

Comment: Please provide the *full* error message.

Comment: I added full error message @deceze

Comment: You performed a SQL injection attack against yourself. You're using string concatenation to construct a SQL query so any unexpected quotes or commas in the values will result in either invalid queries, bad data or damage. Use parameterized queries instead. And **don't** put everything in a single line. Right now you can't see what the query is doing. Use a multiline string in to specify the query string as a variable, eg `sql =""" select ....... """`

Comment: BTW this query is way too long and essentially unreadable. Most of it is just JOINs. You should probably convert it to a view or stored procedure stored in the database.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for answer, by the way I have same query but between start_range and end_range it is working as expected and I get all date which is I need.

Comment: No it's not working as expected  - it simply hasn't crashed yet and you can't see the query itself because it's all in one line. Imagine what would happen if `class_nbr ` contained `1; DROP TABLE USERS; #`. Or `banana`. Just because you added the `_nbr` suffix to the variable doesn't mean it's an integer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic SQL injection scenario caused by concatenating unchecked input to generate queries. String concatenation or interpolation are the root cause for this problem and can't be solved with any amount of quoting or escaping.

The real and *easy* solution is to use parameterized queries. Another significant improvement is creating the query string separately from the call. Putting everything in a single line is neither cleaner, faster nor easier.

```
sql="""select * 
    from qs36f.DSTHSTP 
    join qs36f.calendar on date_ccyymmd = dhindt 
    join qs36f.itemp i on DHITM#=i.ZIITM# 
    join qs36f.subcl2p on i.zisbcl = s2sbcl and i.ziclss = s2clss 
    join qs36f.subclsp on sbclss=s2clss and SBSBCL=s2sbcl 
    where date_iso between(current date - 10 day) and current date 
        and DHCUS# in (?,?,?) 
        and dhqtss >= 1 
        and SBDEPT='MT' 
        AND dhclss = ?
        and ((dhqtss*dhrt5s)*DHPACK) > ?
"""

rows=cursor.execute(sql,shop1,shop2,shop3,class_nbr,start_range)
```

`?` specifies query parameters by position. Parameter values never become part of the query. They are sent to the server as strongly typed values (integers, dates, flaots) outside the query itself. The database compiles the query into a parameterized execution plan and then executes that with the parameter values.

This has several benefits :

- Obviously, SQL injections are eliminated as the values never become part of the string.
- Formatting errors are eliminated because numbers and dates are passed as binary values. You no longer have to worry about `34,56`,  `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY`. You can compare date fields directly against date values, numeric fields with numbers.
- The database can reuse already compiled execution plans for the same query string. That offers significant benefits for big, busy systems.

Comment: I did as you shared and now I got this error   ----pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0010 - String constant beginning "\n       " not delimited. (-10) (SQLPrepare)')

Comment: If DB2 doesn't like a starting newline remove it. Use `"""select ..."

Comment: it takes a lot of time sir --   pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0010 - String constant beginning "select *" not delimited. (-10) (SQLPrepare)')

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the sql starts with 4 ", probably not the problem for Bahruz since python would choke on that. Feel free to reverse my edit if it was your intention.

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini oops, I thought I typed only 3 quotes

Comment: Yes it was starts one was extra and also i forgot to mention open_stores parametr)) now I got another issue(((       ------- Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: @Bahruz, remove parameter by parameter from your query until it works (to pinpoint where the error is). Example sql = """... AND dhclss = ?""" and rows=cursor.execute(sql,shop1,shop2,shop3,class_nbr,) etc. You may want to add a `fetch first 1 rows only` to your query while testing

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini why am i getting this issue do you have any answer about it please.      Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: Did you actually try to execute that query in a tool? We can't guess what your schema is, or what you actually executed, and very few developers have an AS/400 machine handy. It could easily be that the driver has a bug. [`0xC0000409` is the Windows code for a buffer overrun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409809/windows-7-exception-code-0xc0000409)

Comment: Mainframes are quirky and the "driver" may actually be using screen scraping through another service to read data from the mainframe. At least, that's what the mainframe ODBC drivers did back in 2000. That service may have crashed with a buffer overrun

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But I dont face any problem while running other test scenarios.

Comment: @Bahruz, I have no idea. But as mentioned, simplify your query until it works. Then try to figure out why it breaks when you add a particular part of the query

Comment: Hello there are there anyone?