# Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409) on pyside program

Tags: python, stack-overflow

I am trying to run a small Pyside program, I keep running into this error no matter what I do, here is my code. Can't find any info on this online, and my professor has no idea either.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QApplication, QButtonGroup, QRadioButton
import sys


class MyQuiz(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Quiz")

        #Question 1
        radio11 = QRadioButton("1")
        radio12 = QRadioButton("2")
        radio13 = QRadioButton("3")

        groupe_radio = QButtonGroup()
        groupe_radio.addButton(radio11)
        groupe_radio.addButton(radio12)
        groupe_radio.addButton(radio13)

        layout.addWidget(radio11)
        layout.addWidget(radio12)
        layout.addWidget(radio13)



window = MyQuiz()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

I tried, changing the file ( ctrl + c ctrl + v to a fresh file )
clearing the cache on pycharm
reinstalling pyside6

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409809/how-do-you-diagnose-the-exception-code-0xc0000409-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

qapplication is the first thing you want to instantiate. It has nothing to do with your file or cache.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyQuiz()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```