# Debug EXE and DLL files (C++) in Visual Studio using the information from Event Viewer

Tags: c++, dll, crash, event-viewer

Faulting application name: Application.exe, version: 28.11.2022.0, time stamp: 0x6507c0c9

Faulting module name: ModuleName.dll, version: 5.5.2021.0, time stamp: 0x60923739

Exception code: 0xc0000409

Fault offset: 0x000659cc

Faulting process id: 0x20b8

Faulting application start time: 0x01da398e25463d19

Faulting application path: C:\Application\program\Application.exe

Faulting module path: c:\Application\program\ModuleName.dll

Report Id: 94094d0c-3eff-4d83-9b04-a32f166caeff

Faulting package full name:

Faulting package-relative application ID:

====================

The application randomly crashed and I got the above information from the Event Viewer. I have the source codes in C++ of the application and the DLL as well as their PDB files.

- How to debug/find the specific line of code of that fault offset using Visual Studio?
- What does the meaning of the fault offset? Is that the offset from the base address of Application.exe or ModuleName.dll?

I have tried the method in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkAhFhcLn9Q. It works if the application name and module name are the same. But I cant make it work in this case where the faulting module name is different from the faulting application name. Thanks!

Thanks!

====== Update 04/01/2024 =======

I used MSVS to check the disassembly of the program. The fault offset points to the line 22 below. I think the program is using NtSetInformationThread and RtlNtStatusToDosError in ntdll.dll to set the priority of the thread. The program can still work alright, but it crashes once every a few days when running 24/7.

1. ?? ??
2. loopne      _RtlpHpFreeHeap@20+0CCh (77289D9Fh)
3. dec         dword ptr [ebx+2EBFC55h]
4. mov         eax,esi
5. mov         ecx,edi
6. test        eax,eax
7. jne         _RtlpHpFreeHeap@20+0E5h (77289DB8h)
8. lea         ecx,[edi+8]
9. lea         eax,[edx+8]
10. push        eax
11. push        3
12. push        ecx
13. movzx       ecx,byte ptr [edx+2]
14. mov         edx,ebx
15. and         ecx,0Fh
16. call        _RtlpCallInterceptRoutine@20 (77278BE3h)
17. test        eax,eax
18. js          _RtlpHpFreeHeap@20+18Ch (77289E5Fh)
19. test        dword ptr [ebx+0Ch],10000000h
20. je          _RtlpHpFreeHeap@20+12Ch (77289DFFh)
21. push        dword ptr [ebp+8]
22. mov         edx,edi
23. mov         ecx,ebx
24. call        _RtlpHpSizeHeap@12 (7728A63Ch)
25. cmp         eax,0FFFFFFFFh
26. jne         _RtlpHpFreeHeap@20+12Ch (77289DFFh)
27. push        esi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49781951/920069 may be helpful.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)