# .NET app crashes at ntdll.dll on a single german computer

Tags: c#, .net, crash

I got this software working fine on Windows, Linux and MacOS
https://sourceforge.net/projects/converter432hz/

One single user, running German Windows 11, is getting a crash on startup on ntdll.dll

Original german error message:

```
Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: Converter432Hz.exe, Version: 3.3.0.0, Zeitstempel: 0x654116c1
Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: ntdll.dll, Version: 10.0.22621.3085, Zeitstempel: 0xbced4b82
Ausnahmecode: 0xc0000409
Fehleroffset: 0x000000000008ebef
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x0x8750
Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x0x1DA61726FCF3BAD
Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: C:\müll\432_Conv\Converter432Hz-3.3_Win_x64\Converter432Hz.exe
Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Berichtskennung: 8acf8c51-ea18-4925-85ed-38311612742c
Vollständiger Name des fehlerhaften Pakets:
Anwendungs-ID, die relativ zum fehlerhaften Paket ist:
```

Translated error message (provided by a German, might not be the same as the original english error message provided by MS):

```
Name of failed application: Converter432Hz.exe, Version: 3.3.0.0, Timestamp: 0x654116c1
Name of failed assembly: ntdll.dll, Version: 10.0.22621.3085, Timestamp: 0xbced4b82
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Error offset: 0x000000000008ebef
ID of failed process: 0x0x8750
Start time of failed application: 0x0x1DA61726FCF3BAD
Path of failed application: C:\müll\432_Conv\Converter432Hz-3.3_Win_x64\Converter432Hz.exe
Path of failed assembly: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report identifier: 8acf8c51-ea18-4925-85ed-38311612742c
Full name of failed package:
Application-ID relative to failed package:
```

This is super odd. The app doesn't start at all because I'm unable to catch any exception within the app. The only hint we could find is in windows events log.

The app is compiled with .NET 8 embedded.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: First thing I noticed: The path contains the german umlaut `ü` (within the word *müll* which translates to trash btw). Maybe that causes some sort of problem.

Comment: As a native speaker I've gone ahead and translated the german error message to English here. Have you tried googling the exception code yet?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409809/how-do-you-diagnose-the-exception-code-0xc0000409-on-windows

Comment: Is there unsafe code involved? Maybe p/ Invoke? As Klaus linked: the code hints to a buffer overrun which would be pretty hard to do in all managed C#/dotnet

Comment: Often, there's a second entry in the event log, which contains a stack trace. That could be more helpful.

Comment: Try to convince the user to create a [memory dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for you and investigate it for more details.

Comment: It does use BASS audio library https://www.un4seen.com/ Must be a bug in there...