php-cgi.exe crashing under IIS - how to determine which php code is running during crash
I'm running PHP 8.3.12.0 NTS under IIS on Windows Server 2019.  I occasionally get an error in the Windows Application event log that php-cgi.exe has crashed:
Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 8.3.12.0, time stamp: 0x66f31faa Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.17763.6414, time stamp: 0xd2a47020 Exception code: 0xc0000409 Fault offset: 0x00000000000a4fb0 Faulting process id: 0xc78 Faulting application start time: 0x01db3dcdd7800477 Faulting application path: C:\php\php8312nts\php-cgi.exe Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll Report Id: 80de4dc0-2c5c-4d6d-8b18-17238bd88a77 Faulting package full name:  Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Is there any way to determine what PHP code is being executed when this crash occurs (such as php file and line number)?  There is absolutely no mention of an error during the same time in my PHP error log.  This server is running many PHP scripts at the same time so it has proven difficult to find exactly what code is triggering the crash.
I looked at the crash dump report.wer file and it shows that the fault is happening in a Sybase ASE ODBC driver, but this ODBC connection is used in so many places, I really need to determine specifically where in my PHP code the crash happens (or if it's random).
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name Sig[3].Value=sybdrvodb64.dll_unloaded Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version

I don't know much about IIS, but is there any related information found in the web server's error log?

Do your application works fine in local(issue only occurs in IIS)? I saw that something worng with ntdll.dll from the error message. Maybe you can refer to this similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409809/how-do-you-diagnose-the-exception-code-0xc0000409-on-windows

If you have a .dmp file, you can use DebugDiag Tool downloadable from the vendor site. It can give more detail and can make several types of analysis like crashdump, kernel-crash-hang, memory, and also perfomance analysis.

Paul T -- I checked IIS logs and found 500 errors, but it looks like that is happening after the php-cgi.exe process crashed.   I think IIS was trying to execute the next script but since php-cgi.exe had crashed, there was nothing to execute it until a new worker process was invoked.
